# SOQL Query within controller Custom Permission

Tags: apex, soql, permission-sets, compile-error, custom-permission

I'm trying to query what custom permission the current user has.  I will have to query this in a few places so I was trying to avoid putting it in every single controller class.  Maybe putting it in one of our util.cls.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static List<CustomPermission> getCustomPermissions() {
    List<CustomPermission> cusPer = [
    SELECT Id, DeveloperName,
        (select Id, Parent.Name, Parent.Profile.Name from SetupEntityAccessItems)
    FROM CustomPermission
    WHERE DeveloperName = 'ViewLongComments'
    ];
    System.debug('cusPer = ' +  cusPer);
    return cusPer;
}
```

However when I attempt to call this method in the various controllers the compiler says:

> Entity is not api accessible entity name: CustomPermission

Any ideas on a different way I could write this so I can write the query once and call it throughout the various controllers?

Answer (score 0):

That object is definitely queryable, the issue you're seeing is due to security.

From Workbench:

[image]

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_custompermission.htm):

**Supported Calls**

describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()

If you can, mark the class containing your `getCustomPermissions()` method as `without sharing`. If any class that is invoked in the transaction is marked as `with sharing`, it may enforce security on querying this table, depending on how you've defined the sharing for each class. The docs explain how Apex sharing is enforced here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

I would also suggest running a query on this table directly in dev console to make sure nothing funny is going on.

Comment: I can definitely query the table in workbench and dev console.  The class this method is in is marked without sharing.  When I go to call this method from a different class (being my controller class) is when it gives the error.  I'm trying to write the query once and then just call the method that houses it on various controllers to block certain things on the page.